# Versioned containers

Tags: containers, auto-versioning

I'm looking for information on versioned containers, suitable for parallel access in different versions. I don't know if that's the right term, because my searches are yielding very little.

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean "container"? Maybe "[version control](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Revision_control)" system?

If that so then I recommend [SVN](http://subversion.apache.org/).
You can access different versions of anything you've "commited" into it.
Every "commit" gives increased, new, version number.

Comment: Nope. Container. As in, a versioned linked list -- something I can snapshot, or iterate through given a specific version.